# How can I parse yelp's review using Python's urllib standart library?

Tags: python, http, parsing, urllib, yelp

I've got a problem related to the urllib library and HTTP Error 404. Since I started parsing yelps review directly from the web site without using an API(cuz it's extremely restricted), I've faced with a strange behaviour: my standard approach does not work at all. Basically I'm trying to pass some data using POST request to retrieve some specific information(I need to sort reviews and get the newest ones) and avoid shutting me off by using specific headers(The "User-Agent" header helps to hide your parsing bot).
For an axample I took the closest mconalds to me and tried to parse the page. Everything is pretty simle, but I does not work. I know that I can use a simple "GET"(passing a simple string without any additional data as "POST" request can) request, but I'm pretty confident that even "POST" has to work correctly, but I cant find the issue.

```
url = 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/mcdonalds-new-york-139/' # our url
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'} # headers
values = {'sort_by':'date_desc'} # sorting values which help to sort the reviews

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values) # Making the URL encoding
data = data.encode('UTF-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=data, headers=headers) # Creating a POST request
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req) 
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_page = response.read() # Retrieving the data we supposed to get

print(the_page) # An Error 404
```

Can anyone point what I'm doing wrong? "GET" request still works great, but I'd like to use "POST" passing headers and the data query inside the body.

Comment: *Why* are you pretty confident that POST has to work? GET and POST are generally not interchangeable. Also it would be semantically wrong in this case.

Comment: @BlackJack yep, it won't be right semantically, but how would you pass headers and some data like request query without using "POST" at once?

Comment: I don't understand the question‽ I would simply do it. GET doesn't mean you can't change or add headers. Headers are part of every method, not just POST.